# How are manually and electromechanically actuatable switches called?

Tags: switches, relay, mechanical

I'm looking for (the name of) a part that is basically a bistable relay that has a mechanical interface as well, but I don't know how to look for it. I have seen a simpler but similar part in a printer that has a predefinable idle timeout - after which it switches itself off by manipulating its main AC switch that, from the user side, apart from this, looks and behaves exactly like a usual rocker switch. I'm unfortunately not at liberty to take that apart.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There do exist "remote-reset rocker switches". For example, [this](http://omronfs.omron.com/en_US/ecb/products/pdf/en-a8gs.pdf) one from Japan-based manufacturer Omron.

[image]

It's not quite what you are asking for in the question because it can only be turned "off" with the coil, but perhaps it is what you have. Of course the time-out pulse would have to be generated by an external circuit in the case of this particular switch.

Comment: Thanks, at least I know the name of this device. The on/off pulses would be sent by a microcontroller.

Comment: Boy that makes it ridiculously easy to build a [Useless Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Useless_machine)...

Answer (score 1):

There are many industrial bistable switches/relays that do what you want.

This is [one series from ABB](https://library.e.abb.com/public/e10e048824aa43f8c1257b600048516c/1MRK508016-BEN_D_en_Bistable_relays_RXMVB_2_and_RXMVB_4.pdf) that has both coil activation or manual activation/reset  ...another [here from ISKRA](https://www.tme.eu/pl/Document/cfd3ed82a31798e64a1166d39c09981c/ISKRA-Bistable%20relays-EN.pdf)

[image]

Search for bistable switch or relay with manual operation